# Is it OK if I add links to non-English written posts in a SO answer?

Tags: discussion, languages, external-links

Answering this question: [Java/Swing app Freezes randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744771/java-swing-app-freezes-randomly) I've noted that questioner seems to speak Spanish (my native language) and I wanted to add at the end of my answer (as an off-topic comment) two links to a Java blog I've started to write not too long ago.

Let me clarify that the topic treated in those entries is not trivial and I couldn't find good tutorials for that in Spanish language while I was a Java beginner. Matter of fact is not that easy to find a topic like that explained in English either, but there are some good readings around the corner.

Why I've decided to include these links is because beginners who are non-English speakers have to deal with two things: code-language (Java, C#, PHP, whatever it is) and speaking-language, which often conducts to a poor understanding and wrong assumptions.

On the other hand answers are intended to help other developers that have similar problems. Though unlikely, my links could help somebody whose language is Russian or Hindi, for example. So, is it OK to include links to non-English posts in Stack Overflow answers?

Comment: No. Embedded links should be in the same language as your answer: English.

Comment: I don't really see a problem in including a link to a resource in another language as an afterthought, provided you specify that the link is in Spanish and have reason to believe that the questioner speaks that language... just make sure you include a translation of the part relevant to the question in your SO answer so it can benefit the SO community and that you don't just post a link-only answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that SO is not a forum, you are not just answering the question for one user.  Always easy to overlook the next several hundreds of programmers that are going to google your answer, not great odds that they'll be thrilled with an answer that is backed-up with links to Spanish web sites.

Comment: Thanks @eddie_cat that's exactly the case. The links are more like extra ingridients to the answer. The answer itself is in English of course and not a link-only answer.

Comment: You say "as an off-topic comment". If the link isn't relevant to your answer and just promotes your blog it could quite legitimately be edited out even if the blog was written in English. How off topic is it?

Comment: I appreciate your comment @MartinSmith Of course there's no intention to promote nothing. See, the original problem was about multithreading and concurrency in Swing. However in my answer I've added some JPA hints and later in those links I refer to TableModel implementation (all Java stuff). When I answer a question I'd like to take a whole picture of the problem and include not just the answer to the concrete question but all hints/advices I can, based on questioner's code. So I really can't tell how off-topic are those links.

Comment: If it's "an off-topic comment", which is furthermore personally tailored to OP, why not just _post it as a comment to the question or your answer_ instead of including it into the answer?

Comment: You could just contact the OP via other means. A message, email, maybe? That's what I do when I end up posting an answer to another Brazilian or Portuguese member, and I want to give some extra information.

Comment: Or, you know, tell them about Stack Overflow Portuguese if you want to communicate and/or exchange links in Portuguese.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, sure. But I never go there. I don't live in Brazil anymore (for a long time), so I'll stick to the one in English. It was just a suggestion to the OP anyway. :)

Comment: Please correct your post: names of languages are proper nouns in English and must be capitalized, so it should be 'Russian and Hindi', just like Spanish and English...

Comment: Tell them to add a link to a translated version of the link instead.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Provided your answer is on-site, in English, and *complete*, then providing links to *supplementary* material in what you believe to be the questioner's native language is at worst harmless and at best useful to a subset of people finding your answer. As [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) suggests in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271060/is-it-ok-if-i-add-links-to-non-english-written-posts-in-a-so-answer?#comment92614_271061), I would indicate that the linked resource is in Spanish so people don't bother to follow it if they don't read Spanish.

The key here, though, is that your answer should be **useful and complete** even if those links were dead even at the moment you linked them, and even if the person finding your answer can't read Spanish (or Google's translation of it). They really must be *supplementary*. If your answer is incomplete without them, then no, it's not okay.

I treat my *(anemic little)* blog the same way, even though it's written in English, because it's off-site. I never link to it without ensuring that the answer I've posted on SE is complete in and of itself. The link is just an adjunct. The test is: If I deleted my blog, would the answer still be useful and complete?

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a great answer. I think I passed the test and hope it be the best scenario.

Comment: +1. It doesn't matter what language the links use. All links rot. It is worth making any answer self-sufficient -- outside links are always supplementary unless they are the answer.

Comment: I would also add that if you're linking to a page not in English, indicate that after the link by adding something simple such as "(Not in English)" so users know what to expect. There's nothing more annoying than suddenly jumping from an English-only page to a non-English page unexpectedly.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest putting the actual language there instead of "Not in English"...

Comment: @Romiox: Indeed. When I saw animuson's comment, I updated the answer to suggest the same, but with the specific language.

Comment: English speakers using Google Chrome can automatically translate foreign languages into English.

Comment: Yeah, because automatic translation is always perfect. Especially when translating technical articles, where it's easy to just extrapolate and figure out what was probably meant. Oh wait, no, I think I've got that backwards…